# Why is my OpenGL-OpenCL buffer sharing not working properly?

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I am having an unusual problem with an Application that shares an OpenGL Shader Storage Buffer with the OpenCL context to perform data manipulation.

On my desktop computer (Graphics Card: AMD 5700XT) the Application works flawlessly, and generates a rotating windmill image, as expected:

[image: A windmill image. Image is not animated, but in the application proper it rotates.]

However, on my Laptop computer (Graphics Card: AMD Radeon Graphics associated with a AMD Ryzen 7 5700U CPU), I instead get a blank screen, and with other applications I have tested with, I sometimes even get garbage data. I don't even get any errors reported by the application: I just get incorrect rendering.

I also get similar results to my laptop from other test devices: so far, my desktop computer is the only device on which this application runs correctly.

This functionality can be fixed if I disable CL-GL sharing and instead manually transfer data from the OpenGL buffer to the OpenCL buffer, and vice-versa, to synchronize between the buffers. If I do that, the application behaves correctly on all devices (but suffers a loss in performance due to having to manually synchronize the buffers).

So my question is, what is causing this behavior? Have I inadvertently setup the OpenCL-OpenGL sharing incorrectly? Is there an incompatibility that I'm just avoiding on my desktop computer?

```
#include<Utility/OpenCL/CLInclude.h>
#include<Utility/OpenGL/GLInclude.h>
#include<Utility/OpenGL/Buffers.h>
#include<Utility/OpenGL/Shaders.h>
#include<Utility/OpenGL/VertexArray.h>
#include<Utility/OpenCL/DeviceStats.h>
#include<Utility/OpenCL/Error.h>
#include<Window/Window.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#undef min
#undef max
#undef OPTIONAL

#include<iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        const int IMAGE_SIZE = 800;
        window::frame frame{ window::frame::frame_options("CLGLSharing", geom::irect{geom::icorner2{100, 100}, geom::idim2{IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE}}) };
        auto& glContext = frame.get_context();
        glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(frame.get_window_handle(), IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE);
        gl_util::vertex_array vao;
        vao.bind();
        gl_util::shader_storage_buffer image;
        util::Matrix<uint8_t> pixels{ IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE };
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE; i++) {
            pixels(i, i) = 255;
            pixels(i, IMAGE_SIZE - i - 1) = 255;
        }
        image.set_data(pixels, {});
        std::string vertexShaderSRC = R"GL(#version 430
float positions[] = {
    -1, -1,
    -1, 1,
    1, 1,
    1, -1
};

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexID * 2], positions[gl_VertexID * 2 + 1], 0, 1);
}
)GL";

        std::string fragmentShaderSRC = R"GL(#version 430

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer pixels {
    uint data[];
};

layout(location = 0) out vec4 pixelColor;

void main() {
    uvec2 pixelPosition = uvec2(floor(gl_FragCoord.xy));
    if(pixelPosition.x >= 800 || pixelPosition.y >= 800)
        discard;

    uint flatPosition = pixelPosition.y * 800 + pixelPosition.x;
    uint offset = (flatPosition % 4) * 8;
    flatPosition /= 4;
    uint bufferValue = data[flatPosition];
    bufferValue >>= offset;
    bufferValue &= 0xff;
    
    float value = bufferValue / 255.f;
    pixelColor = vec4(value, value, value, 1);
}

)GL";
        gl_util::program glProgram{ gl_util::make_vertex_shader(vertexShaderSRC), gl_util::make_fragment_shader(fragmentShaderSRC) };
        glProgram.bind();
        gl::glBindBufferBase(gl::GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, image);

        auto device = util_cl::chooseDevice();
        cl_context_properties properties[] = {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_PLATFORM>(),
            CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(),
            CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(),
            0
        };
        cl::Context context{ device, properties };
        cl::CommandQueue queue{ context };
        cl::BufferGL buffer{ context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, *image };

        std::string clKernelSRC = R"CL(
kernel void windmill(
    global uchar * pixels,
    float angle
) {
    size_t gx = get_global_id(0), gy = get_global_id(1), width = get_global_size(0), height = get_global_size(1);
    float x = (float)gx - (width / 2), y = (float)gy - (height / 2);
    float testAngle = atan2(y, x);
    size_t pixelCoord = gx + gy * width;
    pixels[pixelCoord] = 0;
    for(int i = -4; i <= 4; i++) {
        if(fabs(testAngle + (i * M_PI_2_F) - angle) <= radians(5.f)) {
            pixels[pixelCoord] = 255;
            break;
        }
    }
}
)CL";
        cl::Program clProgram{ context, clKernelSRC };
        clProgram.build();
        cl::Kernel kernel{ clProgram, "windmill" };
        kernel.setArg(0, buffer);

        while (frame.should_not_close()) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            gl::glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            gl::glClear(gl::GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl::glFlush();

            std::vector<cl::Memory> memObjects{ buffer };
            queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&memObjects);
            queue.finish();
            auto now = glfwGetTime();
            const float PI2 = std::atan2f(0, -1) * 2;
            float timeAsAngle = std::remainderf((float)now, PI2);
            std::cout << "Current Time: " << std::setprecision(8) << std::setw(13) << std::fixed << now << " Current Angle: " << std::setw(13) << timeAsAngle << "\r";
            kernel.setArg(1, timeAsAngle);
            queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
                kernel,
                {},
                { IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE }
            );
            queue.finish();
            queue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&memObjects);
            queue.finish();

            gl::glDrawArrays(gl::GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

            frame.swap_buffers();
        }
    }
    catch (cl::BuildError const& e) {
        auto buildLog = e.getBuildLog();
        for (auto const& [device, log] : buildLog) {
            std::cerr << "Error Building Kernel:\n " << log << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (cl::Error const& e) {
        std::cerr << "CL Error: " << e.what() << ": " << util_cl::to_string(e.err()) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        try {
            std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
        catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "FATAL EXCEPTION: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```